# Obtaining maximum likelihood estimator for $\mu$ in this distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables, estimation, maximum-likelihood

I am stuck on the following question:

Say we have independent and identically distributed random variables $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ which have a dsitribution of $N(\mu,\sigma_0^2)$, where $\sigma_0^2$ is a known variance, then how can we find the maximum likelihood estimator for $\mu$?

Not sure how to proceed, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if you need to show your work then you need to set the derivative of the Gaussian distribution with respect to $\mu$ equal to zero and solve for $\mu$ in terms of $X_1,...,X_n$.

Comment: The joint probability density is $\displaystyle f(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n \varphi_{\mu,\sigma_0} (x_i). $ As a function of $\mu$ this is $\displaystyle L(\mu) = f(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n \varphi_{\mu,\sigma_0} (x_i). $ The problem is to find the value of $\mu$ that maximizes that. How far have you progressed so far in doing this? At what point did you have difficulties.

Comment: @Thoth : If you say simply "the derivative" rather than "the derivative with respect to $\mu$" then your comment will not be easy to understand. However, in the case of the Gaussian distribution, this reduces to minimizing a quadratic function, so doing it by setting the derivative to $0$ cannot be considered necessary.